# How to get distinct values between different levels of a factor variable in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Assume you have a data.table with a number of columns and you are interested in values under a specific column that are distinct to a factor variable (on a different column):

```
> dt <- data.table(name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Charlie", "Bob", "Dennis"), 
+                  time = c("lunch", "dinner", "lunch", "lunch", "lunch", "dinner", "dinner"),
+                  meal = c("sallad", "pasta", "pasta", "pesto", "sandwich", "pizza", "pizza"))
> dt
      name   time     meal
1:   Alice  lunch   sallad
2:   Alice dinner    pasta
3:     Bob  lunch    pasta
4:     Bob  lunch    pesto
5: Charlie  lunch sandwich
6:     Bob dinner    pizza
7:  Dennis dinner    pizza
```

So in this example the I am after the names of the people that have eaten lunch but not dinner, or dinner but no lunch (so the expected result is Charlie for lunch and Dennis for dinner).

I have tried the combination of `group_by` and `distinct` but that doesn't do the trick since it gives me rows where there are distinct names within each mealtime.

```
> dt %>% group_by(time) %>% distinct(name)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
Groups: time [2]

     name   time
    <chr>  <chr>
1   Alice  lunch
2   Alice dinner
3     Bob  lunch
4 Charlie  lunch
5     Bob dinner
6  Dennis dinner
```

I know that I could define two subsets of the data, based on the factor variables and call `setdiff` on those but with several calls of `filter` on each it's a bit cumbersome and not particularly neat either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by grouping with 'name' and `if` the `length` of 'unique` 'time' elements is 1, then get the 'time'

```
dt[, if(uniqueN(time)==1) .(time = time) , name]
#     name   time
#1: Charlie  lunch
#2:  Dennis dinner
```

---

If we want to use `tidyverse`, then

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(time)==1) %>%
    select(-meal)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for including the data.table native and dplyr versions of it